# Can I set background of cefsharp to transparent?

Tags: cefsharp

The default background is white. I am wondering if it is possible to set it to transparent. So I can use the other control(a video player, for example) as a background. The cefsharp is only used to display some text.

I am using cefSharp.WinForms, Version=71.0.0.0

Comment: Unfortunately only the WPF version supports transparency.

Comment: @amaitland Thanks.